# How to use docker secret/environment variable in golang dockertest.resource instead of hardcoded password

Tags: docker, go

We use the below code for unit testing the services that talk to a database system.

https://sergiocarracedo.es/integration-tests-in-golang-with-dockertest/

MySQL root password is hardcoded in the particular line and creates security issues. Is there any way we can pass that as env variable or docker secret ?

resource, err := pool.Run("mysql", "5.7", []string{"MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"})

Comment: Can you clarify your question? You're writing your tests in Go so you can do anything you want. If you provide the password in an environment variable, you can use [`os.Getenv`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Getenv) to retrieve the value from the environment. If you provide the value as a Docker secret, you can use standard file i/o to read the value from the corresponding file.

Comment: I have the password in vault secret. How can i use it in this place ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the environment variable.

1. First of all, get the env variable via `os.Getenv()` in your code

```
mysqlPwd := os.Getenv("MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD")
```

2. Then run the docker with the `-e` option

```
docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
```

Comment: Try not to issues secrets on the command line (will show in history) - use an `envfile` instead.